# What is the minimum sample size for establishing the construct and especially concurrent validity of an intelligence test?

Tags: measurement

For example, the Shipley has a sample size of 263 for concurrent validity and I'm wondering if this is enough. Also, this is a stretch, but does anyone know the concurrent validity of the Figure reasoning test?

Comment: Similar to: [Are there rule of thumb regarding sample size when neuroscientific measurements are used?](https://psychology.stackexchange.com/q/21013/7001), [Method and sample size to test validity and reliability of a scale/ survey](https://psychology.stackexchange.com/q/27271/7001), and [What is a good rough rule of thumb regarding required sample size for questionnaire studies?](https://psychology.stackexchange.com/q/7969/7001)